# Cambiar de pagina con el scroll

Tags: jquery, html

Posiblemente esta pregunta no este permitida por ser tan abierta, pero creo que si ustedes no han visto esto se sorprenderán tanto como yo.

si se fijan en este medio al hacer scroll hacia abajo van cargando noticias nuevas y ademàs de ello cambia la url el titulo etc, todo lo hace muy ràpido y optimizado, no es que sea un cambio de #div, sino que cambia la ruta como tal

> http://www.pulzo.com/mundo/muerte-helmut-kohl/PP288695

mi pregunta es, existe algun plugin para conseguir esto?, o es angular, jquery?

Comment: Puede que esto te ayude un poco, con la pagina que enviaste de ejemplo pasa lo siguiente.

La actualización de la pagina funciona haciendo una consulta json, añade los datos por medio de js y crea un efecto al llegar al final de la pagina, de por si solo es eso, aunque debe ser un poco mas complejo

Quiza te ayude para algo, Saludos de todas formas

Comment: Puede que sea interesante o no , pero su pregunta no deja de ser **demasiado amplia**

Comment: gracias alejo, si tu aporte me va dando ideas, es que, ah!; me enamoró esla primera vez que veo una  página así

Comment: Se llama scroll infinito, y hay mucha información en la web